# Antivirus software for a small business

Tags: windows, antivirus

I'm looking for Windows Antivirus software for a small business (less than 50 people) with approximately 40 Windows desktops/laptops/servers.

We're currently running Kaspersky Endpoint Security (version 8) and have found it troublesome to keep running without issues (there's no dedicated IT department).
We're willing to consider both paid and free solutions, even a more recent version of Kaspersky.

Requirements:

- Centralised management (policies & deployment)
- Easy to install and setup
- Minimal maintenance
- Virus and malware protection (on-demand and scheduled scans)
- Flexible policies for servers & laptops
- Frequent automatic definition updates
- Windows 7 and later
- Server 2003 and later

Bonus points for:

- Simple licensing
- Good reporting
- Email notifications
- Free
- Linux support

Comment: What you mean by centralised management ?

Comment: @ManuJacob - Ability to specify policies, deploy to machines etc... and push them out from a management console on a central server, no need to go to each machine to install/configure.

Comment: Linux support? If you use Linux, why should you be worry about virus?

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Sophos](http://www.sophos.com/en-us.aspx). It is an antivirus that is solely focused on providing security to organisations and businesses. Not all features were listed on their website so I looked up some reviews. Here's the summary:

- Centralised management
- Easy to install and maintain (set-and-forget installation)
- On demand and scheduled virus scans - can also be initiated by users
- Licensed per user, not per computer
- Frequent automatic updates
- Supports [most operating systems](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/enduser-protection-suites/tech-specs.aspx)
- Simple licensing over the network
- Detailed logging and reporting
- Has a 30-day trial version

The downside is that it's *probably* rather expensive (the price is not disclosed on their website, and you have to submit a request for it)

Answer (score 4):

The best and cheap option available is to use Windows Essential suite (Provided all your machines are running Windows 7+ OSes).
Windows Essentials uses less processing power, works in tally with the genuine OS,checks for updates and supports runtime scan and doesn't costs you a penny.

Comment: [License terms](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security-essentials-eula) state that Microsoft Security Essentials may be installed on __up to 10 devices__ in a small business.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Panda Antivirus Free 2016 and I have not had a problem as long as I've used it. Panda Free Antivirus is at the top of free antivirus ranking on AV-TEST.org. You can try it, and you'll never regret it.

1. Easy to install
2. Easy to update
3. Good Virus database engine