# Business Antivirus/Network Security Software for Windows Server

Tags: security, antivirus, windows-server

I run a multiplayer gaming network that deals with the backend stuff such as server listings and accounts, and I am moving it from Amazon Web Services to a dedicated server running VMs.

I never took interest in the cloud security software that Amazon Web Services offers but now that I will self-host the virtual machines, I need to install security software that:

- Is licenced per-user and not per computer (so I can have the host and VMs under a single licence);
- Can monitor network activity (log connections, usage, etc);
- Can be managed from one machine (the host);
- Not too expensive
- **Must run on Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacentre**
- No need for Android or protection for other devices either (I don't want to pay for something I won't use)

Optional extras that would be nice:

- Web control panel (that I can access from another machine via VPN to the host)
- Email/SMS notifications when suspicous activity is detected
- The ability to add a number of computers to the licence as required

This question is similar to [Antivirus software for a small business](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13318/antivirus-software-for-a-small-business), but I want software that focusses on network security rather than antivirus. I also need it to run on Windows Server, which most antivirus programs refuse to do (as they want Windows Server users to purchase business licences, understandably).